# mySql Timestamp Display Conversion

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

I have a table where one of the columns is entered as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I am pulling the data from the table and displaying it on my site. But can't figure out how to convert the date into a more reader friendly format.

Right now it looks like this: **2020-09-17T19:56:24.000Z** (I also need to figure out how to convert to my timezone.)

But I want it to display like this: **09-17-2020 19:56** (would even prefer 07:56pm, but not critical)

I've seen a few examples where you can reformat it during the query.  But all the examples I've seen are pulling just the date.  I'm pulling everything.  I'm fine with running a function on it after the query to convert... but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619202/215552) and [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/215552).

Comment: Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format What you require is commonplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple function using the built-in methods available to Date objects in js. Something like this is probably what you're looking for.

```js
function formatDate(date){
const month = date.getUTCMonth()+1;
const day = date.getUTCDate();
const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
const hours = d.getUTCHours() > 12 ? d.getUTCHours() - 12 : d.getUTCHours();
const minutes = d.getUTCMinutes();

return `${month}-${day}-${year} ${hours}:${minutes}`}
```